# display event in calendar php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, events, calendar

Can someone help me to debug my code? I'm creating a calendar that display the events with event_title and event_date that is stored on the database. The calendar displays the current month of the YEAR. I'm trying to query the events in the db, but the problem is that, nothing from the events show. Here's my code:

```
      <?php 
/* keep going with days.... */
    for($list_day = 1; $list_day <= $days_in_month; $list_day++):
        $calendar.= '<td class="calendar-day"><div style="position:relative;height:100px;">';
        if($list_day == date('d') && $month == date('m') && $year == date('Y')) {
            $calendar.= '<div class = "today"><a href="event.php?&d='.$list_day.'&m='.$month.'&y='.$year.'">'."$list_day".'</a></div>';
        }else {
            /* add in the day number */
            $calendar.= '<div class="day-number"><a href="event.php?&d='.$list_day.'&m='.$month.'&y='.$year.'">'.$list_day.'</a></div>';
        }
        $event_day = $year.'-'.$month.'-'.$list_day;
        if(isset($events[$event_day])) {
            foreach($events[$event_day] as $event) {
                $calendar.= '<div class="event">'.$event['event_title'].'</div>';
            }
        }else {
            $calendar.= str_repeat('<p>&nbsp;</p>',2);
        }               
        $calendar.= '</div></td>';
        if($running_day == 6):
            $calendar.= '</tr>';
            if(($day_counter+1) != $days_in_month):
                $calendar.= '<tr class="calendar-row">';
            endif;
            $running_day = -1;
            $days_in_this_week = 0;
        endif;
        $days_in_this_week++; $running_day++; $day_counter++;
    endfor;     
    /* get all events for the given month */
    $events = array();
    $query = "SELECT event_title, DATE_FORMAT(event_start,'%Y-%m-%d') AS event_start FROM calendar_events WHERE event_start LIKE '$year-$month%'";
    $result = mysql_query($query,$db_link) or die('cannot get results!');
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $events[$row['event_start']][]= $row;
    }

    ?>
```

Thanks in advance. Really need help.

Comment: What is the output of `$query`?

Comment: $year and month are given. But where do they come from? How are your event_start defined? As timestamp or as DATETIME?

Comment: as DATETIME. the $year and $month came from the selected date of user. event_start is the date from the database

Answer (score 0):

Try to do:

```
<?php
// Create connection
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","db_name","user","pass");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$query = "SELECT event_title, DATE_FORMAT(event_start,'%Y-%m-%d') AS event_start FROM calendar_events WHERE event_start LIKE '$year-$month%'";

$sql = mysqli_query($con,$query);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql))
{
    if (!$row)
    {
        echo 'Error';
        exit();
    }
    //Return of query
    echo $row['event_title'].$row['event_start'];
}
?>
```

Then you can save this results wherever you want.

Comment: It doesn't show information in var: $row['event_title']?